# How to add click listener(button) in every row of ListView which is connected to MS SQL?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a `ListView` using [this tutorial](https://parallelcodes.com/android-listview-from-ms-sql-server/) that fetches the information (into a `TextView`) from **MS SQL**.

I want to add button in each row, when the user clicks a button, it should give a toast message.

Comment: Use custom adapters.

Comment: @rmanalo Thank you. Now I can search more. This will help me. Thank you

Comment: No problem. But next time, don't just ask every question you have in mind here. You need to search a lot first before you post that question here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the way to make a button click work is by following these steps:

1. Get your Button view through `findViewById()` and save it to a variable
2. Set a listener on that variable through `setOnClickListener()`
3. Implement it's `onClick()` overriden method to do what you want. (here is where you will show your toast).

   For Example (taken from the tutorial you presented):

```
public class CountryList extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnview);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //This command shows a Toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your message goes here" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

On the above code the line that creates the Toast is inside the `onClick()` method and it takes 3 parameters :

- context: Which is the context of where you will create the toast (this is usually an activity or a fragment, in this case in can be `this`  as you are referring to the CountryList activity.
- message: The message which the Toast will show
- length: The length of the Toast, usually `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.

Here are references to: [Toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) and [Click Listeners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events)
If you're interested in Android Development, I would also recommend looking into Kotlin and trying more recent tutorials as the one you followed seems a bit outdated.

Good luck.